# after submit is pressed site refreshes from the beginning

Tags: php, submit, isset

I'm new here and in PHP, I was trying to make a "simple" test of my skills but I can't help my self at this point:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
//zweiter Formular test

//$anzahl = $_POST['anzahl'];

function step1($anzahl){
    if($anzahl > 0){
        echo '<h3>Schritt 2</h3>';
        echo '<p>Alles klar, bitte gib den<b> ' . $anzahl . '</b> Feldern namen </p>';
        echo '<form action="formular1.php" method="post">';
            for($i=1; $i<=$anzahl; $i++){

                echo $i . '. Feld <input name="' . $i . '_feld"/> <br/>';

                }
        echo '<p> <input name="anzahl" type="hidden" value=' . $anzahl . ' />
        <input name="submit1" type="submit" /><input type="reset" /></p></form>';

        if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
            step2($_POST['anzahl']);
    }else
        echo '';
}

function step2($anzahl){
    echo '<h3>Schritt 3</h3>';
    echo '<p>Alles klar, hier dein Formular:</p>';

    $feld_namen = array();

    //Trägt post-werte in array ein
    for($j=1; $j <= $anzahl; $j++){
        $feld_namen[$j] = $_POST[$j . '_feld'];
        }

    //print_r($feld_namen);

    echo '<form action="formular1.php" method="post">';
        for($i=1; $i<=$anzahl; $i++){
                //array hier lesen      
                //echo $i . '. <input name="' . $i . '_feld_value" /> <b>' . $_POST[$i . '_feld'] . '</b>  <br/>';
                echo $i . '. <input name="' . $i . '_faled_value" /> <b>' . $feld_namen[$i] . ' </b> <br/>';
            }
        echo '<p><input name="submit2" type="submit" /><input type="reset" /></p></form>';

        if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
            step3();
}

function step3(){
    echo '<h3>Schritt 3</h3>';
    }

?>
```

The Problem starts at function step2, maybe I'm just blind but it says when th button with the name submit2 is set, the page shoud refresh and actually go to step3. But it does not, the page just starts at the beginning.

Am I thinking to much in Java or Something?

I know its not really a beatiful script but I'm trying step by step

here is where the script shoudl start:

```
<h3>Schritt 1</h3>
<form action="formular1.php" method="post">
<p>Wieviele eingabe Felder brauchst du ?</p>
<p>Ich brauche <input name="anzahl" size="2px" /> Felder</p>
<p><input type="submit" /><input type="reset" /></p>
</form>
<?php step1($_POST['anzahl']) ?>
```

Comment: Where are you actually calling a function?

Comment: turn on error reporting if youre trying to debug.

Comment: PHP is state-less, that means that on each call of the page, all you have is what GET/POST gives you. Basically, to solve your problem, you must decide in the top, if (depending on the GET/POST given) you are in step1, 2 or 3. - feel free to make an answer off this ;)

Comment: @kinkero in the 2. code block

Comment: Oh, and I would suggest you to read about the basics of PHP... Maybe in some book! Specially if you want to make some public page, you'd better be understanding what you are doing ;)

Comment: @Theolodis I understand what u mean, but I can't say how to solve the problem anyway, even if it is stateless

Comment: See the new answer, that is what i meant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you are showing the second step. Now the user clicks the submit button and `$_POST['submit2']` will be set. However, `$_POST['submit1']` won't be set anymore (as the user didn't click on it).

So your code will never activate `step2()` which is needed for `step3()` to be called. You can resolve this quite easily by using a hidden input field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit1">
```

in your step2. But a more clean solution would be to call these methods in another way. Eg like this

```
if (isSet($_POST['submit1'])) {
    step2();
} elseif (isSet($_POST['submit2'])) {
    step3();
} else {
    step1();
}
```

Comment: thx a loti just understnd now what the hell i was doing worn the hole time, like this it looks even more like i wanted it to look like.